# Resizing an <amp-iframe> using srcdoc?

Tags: javascript, iframe, amp-html

Is it possible to create a resizable `amp-iframe` when using the `srcdoc` attribute? For an `amp-iframe` to resize, the [docs say the following:](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/#resizable-iframes)

> - The amp-iframe must set the allow-same-origin sandbox attribute.
> - The amp-iframe must be defined with the resizable attribute.
> - The amp-iframe must have an overflow child element.
> - The iframe document must send an embed-size request:

Then, dispatch the following event:

```
window.parent.postMessage({
  sentinel: 'amp',
  type: 'embed-size',
  height: document.body.scrollHeight
}, '*');
```

However, when I try to add the `allow-same-origin` attribute to my iframe, I get the following error in my console: "allow-same-origin is not allowed with the srcdoc attribute."

That appears to be by design, for security concerns, at least according to the code [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/dc66a9ee6c4174c7c309cad8d72555f38c51a0cf/extensions/amp-iframe/0.1/amp-iframe.js#L216), because a `srcdoc` will not be constrained by cross-origin domain protections.

Does that mean that there's no way to dynamically resize an `amp-iframe` that's populated via `srcdoc`?

Am I missing something basic about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - resizing via srcdoc is not possible at the moment. If you think it should be OK for resizing to work without `allow-same-origin`, I'd suggest filing a feature request on Github.

Comment: Thanks. That was what my experiments seemed to indicate as well. I understand the security concerns, but would love to find an effective solution.